# Struggling to implement the bezier quadratics in my code and was wondering if someone could take a look over it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bezier

So here is what I have tried:

```
def bezier(a):
# find order of curve from number of control points
n = np.shape(a)[0]-1
# initialise arrays
B = np.zeros([101, 2])
terms = np.zeros([n+1, 2])
# create an array of values for t from 0 to 1 in 101 steps
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
# loop through all t values
for i in range(0, 101):
    #calculate terms inside sum in equation 13
    for j in range(0, n + 1):

        terms[j,:] = (1 - t[i])**2 * a[0,:] + 2 * t[i] * (1 - t[i]) * a[1,:] + t[i]**2 * a[2,:]
    #sum terms to find Bezier curve
    B[i, :] = sum(terms, 0)
# plot Bezier
pl.plot(B[:, 0], B[:, 1])
# plot control points
pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'ko')
# plot control polygon
pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'k')
return B
```

with:

```
a = np.array([[0, 0], [0.5, 1], [1, 0]])
B = bezier(a)
```

and it is returning:
[this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68adt.png)
which as you can see does not correspond to my control points

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The black curve (well ... graphic) is what you get. What is the blue curve?

Comment: It looks like your t value is not normalized. You need to normalize it so that 0 <= t <= 1.

Comment: Next time please submit a code that is ready to run. As someone who usually works in other languages I had to spend quite some time figuring out I need to import `numpy`, `pyplot` and how to use `show()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sum over `j` is redundant. What happens is that you create your Bezier curve but sum it three times, thus obtaining something that is three times as big as it should.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def bezier(a):
    # find order of curve from number of control points
    n = np.shape(a)[0]-1
    # initialise arrays
    B = np.zeros([101, 2])
    terms = np.zeros([n+1, 2])
    # create an array of values for t from 0 to 1 in 101 steps
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
    # loop through all t values
    for i in range(0, 101):
        #calculate terms inside sum in equation 13
        B[i, :] = (1 - t[i])**2 * a[0,:] + 2 * t[i] * (1 - t[i]) * a[1,:] + t[i]**2 * a[2,:]
    # plot Bezier
    pl.plot(B[:, 0], B[:, 1])
    # plot control points
    pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'ko')
    # plot control polygon
    pl.plot(a[:, 0], a[:, 1],'k')
    return B

a = np.array([[0, 0], [0.5, 1], [1, 0]])
B = bezier(a)
pl.show()
```

[image: Graph of the correct curve]

I would also recommend renaming `a` to something more descriptive such as `controlPts`.